# How to make the pattern of svg editable in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

Here is an svg filled with `<pattern>`.

```html
<svg width="600" height="180">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="carrot" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="50" height="50">
     <path fill="darkorange" d="M30 13c-1-3-5-4-7-2h-1l1-11h-3l-1 
                                9-4-7-3 1 5 8-8-4-1 2 9 5h-1c-2 
                                2-3 5-2 7l2 2 5-3 1 2-5 3 8 9 5-3 
                                2 2-5 3 12 14 3-2-8-25-5 3-1-2 5-3-3-8"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="lightgreen"/>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#carrot)"/>
</svg>
```

I try to edit this svg in Adobe Illustrator, but I find the pattern cannot be edited.
When I scale this svg, the size of icons will not change. When I move the svg, the pattern will not move. I can change the color of the background rectangle, but I can't change the pattern's color.

Current svg:

[image: scale svg in Adobe Illustrator]

I want to treat the pattern as part of the svg and editable in Adobe Illustrator. For example, when I scale the svg, the icons of the pattern will scale equally. I can change one of the icon's color.

Expected svg:

[image: Expected result]

Do you know if creating an svg like this is possible using code?

*Update:* I tried `patternUnits="objectBoundingBox"`

```html
<svg width="600" height="180">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="carrot" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="0.1" height="0.3">
     <path fill="darkorange" d="M30 13c-1-3-5-4-7-2h-1l1-11h-3l-1 
                                9-4-7-3 1 5 8-8-4-1 2 9 5h-1c-2 
                                2-3 5-2 7l2 2 5-3 1 2-5 3 8 9 5-3 
                                2 2-5 3 12 14 3-2-8-25-5 3-1-2 5-3-3-8"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="lightgreen"/>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#carrot)"/>
</svg>
```

When I open the objectBoundingBox svg in the Adobe Illustrator, there is only background but no pattern.

[image: objectBoundingBox svg in the Adobe Illustrator]

When I set `patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"`, the pattern still cannot be edited.

```html
<svg width="600" height="180">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="carrot" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="0.2" height="0.3">
     <path fill="darkorange" d="M30 13c-1-3-5-4-7-2h-1l1-11h-3l-1 
                                9-4-7-3 1 5 8-8-4-1 2 9 5h-1c-2 
                                2-3 5-2 7l2 2 5-3 1 2-5 3 8 9 5-3 
                                2 2-5 3 12 14 3-2-8-25-5 3-1-2 5-3-3-8" transform="scale(0.005)"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="lightgreen"/>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#carrot)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: That's how userSpaceOnUse units work. Perhaps you should use objectBoundingBox units instead.

Comment: I tried objectBoundingBox, but it does not work.

Comment: When I open the objectBoundingBox svg with Illustrator, there is only background, no pattern. I updated the code I tried and the result to my question.

Comment: I changed the values, and set `width="0.1" height="0.3"`. The pattern can show correctly when I click "Run code snippet", but when I save it to .svg file and open in Illustrator, the pattern will disappear.

Comment: you need to change [patternContentUnits](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/pservers.html#PatternElementPatternContentUnitsAttribute), not patternUnits

Comment: I tried `<pattern id="carrot" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="0.1" height="0.3">`. The pattern will not show when I run the code.

Comment: Did you change the path d attribute so the values are in the range 0..1 or alternatively scale transform the path so its in that range?

Comment: Now the pattern correctly shows when I run the code and in Illustrator. But the pattern still cannot be edited in Illustrator, same as the original userSpaceOnUse version. I also updated the code to my question.

Comment: Maybe try a different editor then. Which editor to use isn't really on-topic on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to transform a pattern in Illustrator you have to turn on the option: `Transform both` (or `Transform Pattertn Only`) in the palette 'Transform':

[image]

If you're using scripts to run Illustrator for this task I believe this preference can be toggled via a script. Let me know if you need help.